# I have output combination of var name and var value like 0= , 1= , 10= ,etc in random order and I need to sort it like 0= ,1= , 2= , 3= , etc

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, pulp

I have some code for linear programming using PuLP module and I want to print the output by sorting it in the ascending order. I tried using sorted() method but unfortunately it doesn't work in this case as the output is not the list. Also, the output (as written below) is the combination of some variable name and variable value which I want to print together separated by "=" sign.

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
from pulp import *
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd
from pulp import solvers
import xlrd
import os

vName = list()
vValue = list()
wName = list()
wValue = list()

PriceData=open('C:\Fourth Term @ Dal\Project\Collaboration\Sensitivity analysis\GUI\Otherdata\pricedata.txt', 'r')
line1= PriceData.readlines()

wb=load_workbook(filename="C:\Fourth Term @ Dal\Project\Collaboration\Sensitivity analysis\GUI\Price Data\\"+ line1[0].strip())
ws=wb['Sheet1']

OC_Data=open('C:\Fourth Term @ Dal\Project\Collaboration\Sensitivity analysis\GUI\Otherdata\OC_Data.txt', 'r')
line2= OC_Data.readlines()

OC=open('C:\Fourth Term @ Dal\Project\Collaboration\Sensitivity analysis\GUI\Operating Characteristics\\'+ line2[0].strip())
line3= OC.readlines()

Horizon=int(line1[1][10:])
pieces=int(line3[4][29:])

T=list(range(Horizon))
L=list(range(pieces))

p=[0 for j in range(Horizon)] 
UB=[0 for l in range(pieces)]
LB=[0 for l in range(pieces)]
f=[0 for l in range(pieces)]
g=[0 for l in range(pieces)]

for j in range(Horizon):
    p[j]=ws.cell(row=967, column=j+2).value

UB[0]=float(line3[6][5:])
UB[1]=float(line3[10][5:])
UB[2]=float(line3[14][5:])

LB[0]=float(line3[5][5:])
LB[1]=float(line3[9][5:])
LB[2]=float(line3[13][5:])

f[0]=float(line3[7][6:])*30.5
f[1]=float(line3[11][6:])*30.5
f[2]=float(line3[15][6:])*30.5

g[0]=float(line3[8][6:])*30.5
g[1]=float(line3[12][6:])*30.5
g[2]=float(line3[16][6:])*30.5


Cap=float(line3[3][10:])

M=Cap

prob= LpProblem("EL-NR", LpMaximize)

v = LpVariable.matrix("v", (T),0, None, LpContinuous)
w = LpVariable.matrix("w", (T),0, None, LpContinuous)
I = LpVariable.matrix("I", (T),0, None, LpInteger)
z = LpVariable.matrix("z", (T), 0, 1, LpBinary)
lb= LpVariable.matrix("lambda", (T,L,L), 0, 1, LpContinuous)
mu= LpVariable.matrix("mu", (T,L,L), 0, 1, LpContinuous)
r=  LpVariable.matrix("r", (T,L), 0 ,1, LpBinary)
zz= LpVariable.matrix("zz", (T,L,L),0, 1,LpBinary)
xx= LpVariable.matrix("xx", (T,L,L),0,1,LpBinary)

prob+= (lpSum([p[t]*(-v[t]+w[t]) for t in T]))

for t in T:
    prob+= w[t]<=I[t]
    prob+= w[t]<=M*z[t]
    prob+= v[t]<=M*(1-z[t])
    prob+= I[t]<=Cap
    prob+= lpSum([r[t][l] for l in L])==1

def constraint_1(t,L):
    value = 0
    for l in L:
        for k in L:
            if k>=l:
                value+= lb[t][l][k]*f[k]
    return value

def constraint_2(t,L):
    value = 0
    for l in L:
        for k in L:
            if k<=l:
                value+= mu[t][l][k]*g[k]
    return value

for t in T:
    prob+=v[t]<= constraint_1(t,L)   
    prob+=w[t]<= constraint_2(t,L) 


for t in T:
    for l in L[:pieces-1]:
        for k in L:
            if k==l:
                prob+= lb[t][l][k]<=((UB[l]-I[t])/f[l])+M*(1-r[t][l])

    for l in L:
        for k in L:
            if k>l:
                prob+= lb[t][l][k]<=((UB[k]-UB[k-1])/f[k])+M*(1-r[t][l])

    for l in L:
        for k in L:
            if k>=l:
                prob+= lpSum([lb[t][l][k] for k in L])==r[t][l]

    for l in L[1:]:
        for k in L:
            if k==l:
                prob+=mu[t][l][k]<=((I[t]-LB[l])/g[l])+M*(1-r[t][l])

    for l in L:
        for k in L:
            if k<l:
                prob+=mu[t][l][k]<=((LB[k+1]-LB[k])/g[k])+M*(1-r[t][l])

            if k<=l:
                prob+= lpSum([mu[t][l][k] for k in L])==r[t][l]

            if k>=l:
                prob+=lb[t][l][k]<=zz[t][l][k]

            if k<=l:
                prob+=mu[t][l][k]<=xx[t][l][k]

            for kr in L:
                if k>=l:
                    if kr>k:
                        prob+=zz[t][l][k]>=zz[t][l][kr]


            for kr in L:
                if k<=l:
                    if kr<k:    
                        prob+=xx[t][l][k]>=xx[t][l][kr]    

            prob+=lb[t][l][k]>=0
            prob+=mu[t][l][k]>=0

    if t>0:
        b=t-1
        prob+= I[t]==I[b]+v[b]-w[b]

prob+= I[0]==float(line3[1][25:])

prob.solve(GUROBI())

for v in prob.variables(): 
    if v.name[:1]=="v":
        a=v.name[1:]
        vName.append(a)
        b=v.varValue
        vValue.append(b)
        print(v.name[2:]+'='+ str(b))

This is what I am getting:
0=0.0
1=-0.0
10=-0.0
11=0.0
12=0.0
13=0.0
14=0.0
15=274000.0
16=189500.0
17=183000.0
18=0.0
19=0.0
2=0.0
20=251140.00000618323
21=46707.99999497511
22=0.0
23=0.0
3=0.0
4=274000.0
5=189500.0
6=170500.0
7=183000.0
8=183000.0
9=0.0

And this is what I need:
0=0.0
1=-0.0
2=0.0
3=0.0
4=274000.0
5=189500.0
6=170500.0
7=183000.0
8=183000.0
9=0.0
10=-0.0
11=0.0
12=0.0
13=0.0
14=0.0
15=274000.0
16=189500.0
17=183000.0
18=0.0
19=0.0
20=251140.00000618323
21=46707.99999497511
22=0.0
23=0.0
```

I would appreciate if someone could answer this. TIA :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you....

Replace

```
for v in prob.variables(): 
    if v.name[:1]=="v":
        a=v.name[1:]
        vName.append(a)
        b=v.varValue
        vValue.append(b)
        print(v.name[2:]+'='+ str(b))
```

With:

```
for t in T: 
    print(str(t) + '=' + str(v[t].varValue))
```